# Trigger to update specific cell of another table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have these 2 tables:

```
dbo.Restaurants(rid,name,phone,area,address,zip,desc,foodtype,avgRating)
```

and

```
dbo.Reviews(rev_id,rest_id,user_id,taste, service,environment,value,average,comment)
```

I've been trying to create a trigger that does this:
when a row on dbo.Reviews is deleted,updated or inserted, the trigger then calculates the new average rating for the restaurant like so:

```
select rid, round(avg(average)*20,0) as 'average' 
from dbo.Restaurants inner join dbo.Reviews on rid=rest_id 
group by rid
```

And then updates the avgRating cell on dbo.Restaurants where dbo.Restaurants.rid= dbo.Reviews.rest_id .

So far I've come up with this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [defAverage]
ON [dbo].[Reviews]
AFTER UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN

select rid, round(avg(average)*20,0) as 'average' 
from Restaurants inner join Reviews on rid=rest_id 
group by rid
order by 'average' desc
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    UPDATE [dbo].[Restaurants]
    SET [dbo].[Restaurants].avgRating = 'average'
    where [dbo].[Reviews].rest_id = [dbo].[Restaurants].rid

END
```

Which obviously does not work, otherwise I wouldn't be here. 
I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 which uses SQL Server Tools 2012.

Thanks in advance for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

There are two pseudo tables named `inserted` and `deleted` which are available in DML triggers only. For obvious reasons `inserted` table is empty in the case of `delete`, `deleted` is empty in the case of `insert` and in the case of `update` both tables are populated. And you can use them in the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [defAverage]
ON [dbo].[Reviews]
AFTER UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON
UPDATE [dbo].[Restaurants]
    SET avgRating = round(avg(rv.average)*20,0)
from Restaurants r inner join Reviews rv on r.rid=rv.rest_id 
where r.rid in (select rest_id from inserted
                union
                select rest_id from deleted)
group by r.rid

END
```